# How frequently do Amazon CloudFront objects expire?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

The answer I can find in the [FAQ](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/GettingStartedGuide/index.html?NextSteps.html) is as follows

> An object stays in an edge location
>   until it expires. After the object
>   expires, CloudFront must go back to
>   the origin server the next time that
>   edge location needs to serve that
>   object. By default, all objects
>   automatically expire after 24 hours.

However, I've been noticing recently that objects seem to be getting updated much more frequently than this. I tested a text file and changed it, and within the hour it reflected the change.

I'm just not clear if this was a fluke - or if they changed the expiration rules. Is this country/region specific - or were they just doing routine maintenance at the exact hour I tested (unlikely!) ?

Answer (score 4):

The file isn’t necessarily cached on all of CloudFront’s edge servers. You may have retrieved the file from one location the first time, and a different edge server the second time.

You can see where the file is coming from by examining the `Via` HTTP header, which you can view by doing: `curl -i http://your.url/`.

Comment: i'll check this using Fiddler. thanks for the tip. i'm in the same location with the same IP though. i'm just wondering if theyre trialing this change because a value 24 hours i'm sure is losing them a lot of customers for many applications

Comment: Even with the same IP, your requests are likely hitting one of many different CloudFront servers at a particular AWS datacenter.

Answer (score 0):

CF use many servers which you can test by requesting the same file a few times while you tail the access log files. Then you will notice several different IP addresses requesting the file with the CloudFront user-agent.